# Accessing Xdata on 8051 with IAR C Compiler

Tags: external, iar, 8051

I am having trouble correctly declaring a pointer in the IAR Embedded Workbench to access external RAM connected on the EMI port of an CC8051F121.
Any example code or pointer to example would be appreciated
Thank You
Regards

Answer (score 0):

See [IAR's support article on 8051 programming](https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/important-points-in-8051-programming/).

So a pointer to an int in xdata would be like:

```
int __xdata *myptr;
```

The attribute ensures only MOVX instructions are emitted in assembly, as required by the [C8051F121 datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/C8051F12x-13x.pdf).

[See also this app note.](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/compiler/declare-a-pointer-to-a-specific-address/)